# Hibernate Search: Lock held by another program: var/lucene/indexes/com.org.Recipe/write.lock

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search 5.5.4, while adding new record to the database this Exception occurred and the data is successfully inserted to database but the index was not created

Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: var/lucene/indexes/com.org.Recipe/write.lock

Answer (score 1):

That literally means what the error is saying: there is another process still running which is "owning" the lock on the index.

That is very likely another instance of Hibernate Search; for example this happens if you started your application before, and didn't shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

Ya its solved, the problem was I tried to persists the data by `session.save()` when I change that to `session.persist()` the problem is gone the index value can update only at persist, update, delete etc.

Comment: Sorry but I'm sure that has nothing to do with it. Both save() and persist() will trigger an indexing operation, if one is needed.